# Php Predefined scheduled tasks Cron?

Tags: php, cron

I want to create a script that runs at scheduled times and posts new content to my website. But the times it should run are not consistent. I may want to post data on a monday at 9am then tuesday at midday and so forth.

I was thinking of creating a database and each piece of content can be saved into that with a display time. Then creating a cron to run every hour and check if any new content should be added can determine what is output.

Although this seems like a intensive overly complicated approach.

Are there any ways to run a cron once on a particular data and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `publishedAt`-column and extend your query, so that it will return only results, where `NOW() >= publishedAt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "at" tool.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-job-scheduling/index.html#N10181